# Resize images when upload

Tags: php

I am very new to Resize image in php.Basically i wanted to make thumbnail image using uploaded image. i have used below code but its not working, can anybody help me?.. Thanks in Advance...

```
if($_FILES['logo2_1']['name'])
{
        $uniq = substr( md5(uniqid (rand())), 0, 10 );
        $ext = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES['logo2_1']['name'], '.'), 1));
        $allwd = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');
        if (in_array( $ext , $allwd ))
        {


            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo2_1']['tmp_name'], $upload_dir['path']."/".$uniq.".".$ext)){
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['logo2_1']['tmp_name'], $upload_dir['path']."/".$uniq.".".$ext);
            $logo2_1 = $upload_dir['path']."/".$uniq . '.' . $ext;
            //$logo_1 = "yes";
            }
            else 
            {$logo2_1 = "no00";}
        }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a really nice library to do this called phpThumb.
    http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/

It works well and is well documented.